# How to extract submatrix form a matrix?

Tags: javascript, html

Consider a matix `A=[a_i,j]` `for i,j<=4`. I want to extract a submatrix, namely `A3=[a_i,j]` but `for i,j=3,4` (quadratic matrix 2x2 in the right-hand side corner at the bottom) Here's my code. Finally, I get "the object does not support properties or the method push". Do you know what is wrong?

```js
var n = 4;
var A = [];
var arr1 = [2, 1, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [6, 4, 1, 2];
var arr3 = [5, 3, 9, 7];
var arr4 = [1, 3, 2, 1];
A.push(arr1);
A.push(arr2);
A.push(arr3);
A.push(arr4);
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = A;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = A[2][2];

function a(i, j) {
  return A[i - 1][j - 1];
}
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = a(3, 3);

var A3 = [];
for (i = n - 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
  for (j = n - 1; j < n + 1; j++) {
    A3 = A3.push(a(i, j));
  }
}
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = A3;
```

```html
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo4"></p>
<p id="demo5"></p>
```

Comment: you shouldnt use A3 = A3.push(a(i, j));, .push returns the length of the array after push. just use A3.push(a(i, j))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not assign `A3.push()` to `A3`, this is why you are getting this error.

From MDN:

> [`Array.push()` returns] the new `length` property of the object upon which the method was called.

```js
var n = 4;
var A = [];
var arr1 = [2, 1, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [6, 4, 1, 2];
var arr3 = [5, 3, 9, 7];
var arr4 = [1, 3, 2, 1];
A.push(arr1);
A.push(arr2);
A.push(arr3);
A.push(arr4);
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = A;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = A[2][2];

function a(i, j) {
  return A[i - 1][j - 1];
}
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = a(3, 3);

var A3 = [];
for (i = n - 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
  for (j = n - 1; j < n + 1; j++) {
    A3.push(a(i, j));
  }
}
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = A3;
```

```html
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo4"></p>
<p id="demo5"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the rows and map sliced cols.

```js
var array = [[2, 1, 3, 4], [6, 4, 1, 2], [5, 3, 9, 7], [1, 3, 2, 1]],
    pos = { i: 2, j: 2 },
    size = { i: 2, j: 2 },
    result = array
        .filter((_, i) => i >= pos.i && i < pos.i + size.i)
        .map(a => a.slice(pos.j, pos.j + size.j))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
function getSubMatrix(matrix, startRow, startCol, length) {
    return matrix.slice(startRow, startRow + length).map(row => row.slice(startCol, startCol + length));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.push` add element to `Array` and return `length` of that `Array` (after add element).

You try use:

```
A3.push(<something>)
```

instead of

```
A3 = A3.push(<something>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I couldn't find an answer I liked so I wrote my own.

This only works on square matrices but it can be easily modified to use rectangular multi-dimensional arrays as well.

Simply add a default parameter of height.  default to false.   check at start of function if it's false.  if not, us it's value as the height, and the original width parameter is the width.

---

Oh, and just to answer the question that I'm sure multiple people already pointed out.

You are assigning A3 the return value of Array.prototype.push() which returns an integer length of the resulting array after the push operation.

(Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

---

Anyway, here we are, without nested For loop ;)

```
/*/
getSubmatrix():
matrix = multi-dimensional array or matrix
coords = array; starting point (top left of matrix)
width = integer; width/height of desired submatrix
/*/

const getSubmatrix = (matrix, coords, width) => {
      let tmp, submatrix = matrix.slice(coords[0], coords[0]+width)
    const retern = [];

    for (let i=0;i<submatrix.length;i++) {
       tmp = submatrix[i].slice(coords[1], coords[1]+width)
       retern.push(tmp)
    }
    return retern
}
```

Part of a larger project ([rotateStarWithinMatrix](https://github.com/brianjpatterson/rotateStarWithinMatrix/blob/main/rotateStarWithinMatrix.js)) available here:
https://github.com/brianjpatterson/rotateStarWithinMatrix/blob/main/rotateStarWithinMatrix.js